# Apartment: uninitialized constant Tenant (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, apartment-gem

I am using the [Apartment Gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) for the first time for Multitenancy in a Ruby on Rails project. I am trying to create multiple tenants for users in your digital library Rails application.

I am using [Devise Gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for the authentication of the application, and I have generated the and I have generated config file by running the code below in my terminal

```
rails generate devise:install
```

I have also generated a **User** model for **Devise** using the code below in my terminal

```
rails generate devise User
```

And for the **Apartment Gem**, I have installed it and generated the config file by running the code below in my terminal

```
bundle exec rails generate apartment:install
```

I have also configured the `config/initializers/apartment.rb` initializer file as needed using the documentation provided, but when I run the command below in my terminal

```
rails generate devise:views
```

to generate the views for **Devise**, I get the error below

> uninitialized constant Tenant (NameError)

I have tried to figure out the cause of the issue, but I still haven't been fortunate to get it fixed. I need some help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I later realized that the issue was from the configuration that I made initially to **Apartment Gem's** `config/initializers/apartment.rb` initializer file.

After creating the **User** model, I also added it to the excluded models list in the `config/initializers/apartment.rb` initializer file.

```
config.excluded_models = %w[Tenant User]
```

I was supposed to instead replace `Tenant` in the excluded models list with the `User` model.

```
config.excluded_models = %w[User]
```

And that fixed the issue for me.

**N/B:** If I named the model name of my subdomain for the multiple tenants as `Tenant`, then I the configuration can be left like this

```
config.excluded_models = %w[Tenant]
```

But for my case, I named the model name of my subdomain for the multiple tenants as `User`

That's all.

**I hope this helps**